# Eclipse is ignoring workspace plug-ins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi

Some background: I'm using Eclipse 3.7 (for RCP developers) to work on a few plug-ins that are part of a large (hundreds of plug-ins) RCP application built using Maven with Tycho.  I've set up the target platform and the run configuration, and everything builds fine and seems to run fine except...

The changes I make to plug-ins I have in my workspace are not taking effect.  In particular, when I debug the application near the changes I've made, the running version of the class is clearly not synchronized with the source code I'm seeing.

I have "Launch with: all workspace and enabled target plug-ins" chosen in the run configuration.  If I change it to "plug-ins selected below", the workspace plug-ins are checked in favor of the same plug-ins from the target platform, but my changes are still being ignored at runtime.

Google hasn't been very helpful, and the solutions to similar problems reported by others on SO (e.g. reload the target platform) haven't solved my problem.

Comment: Make sure you have -clean as a part of your Program arguments on the Arguments tab.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc All that seemed to do was make the launch take longer; it's still using the target platform version of the plugins, not the workspace one.